# OnResume() not called by Pressing back Button in ActivityGroup

Tags: java, android

As ActivityGroup manages the Activities in the form of view, so when I try to return back to the Parent Activity that called the child Activity in ActivityGroup the onResume() is not being called.

I tried calling the OnResume() like this.

```
((Activity)view.getContext()).onResume();
```

But its not working, instead finish() is working is fine for me.

```
((Activity)view.getContext()).finish();
```

So, I am able to get the Activity from the View, but not able to call the onResume(), any idea will be appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, when you press back button using ActivityGroup.

```
public void back()
    {
     if ( arrList.size() > 1 )
      {
       arrList.remove(arrList.size() - 1);
       View v = arrList.get(arrList.size() - 1);

       Activity_name object = ((Activity_name)v.getContext());
       object.onResume();
       setContentView(v);
      }
     else {
      this.finish();
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`onResume` is a lifecycle method called by OS when activity comes to the top of the stack. You can't call it directly.

Comment: As far as I know onResume() get's called when we return to the Activity after it is called once, but in this case onResume() is not getting called, So for that reason I had to call it directly.

Comment: It is called after onCreate() and after the app is resumed following an onPause(). There is no place appropriate for you to call it directly. Ever

Comment: I am not sure how you made a determination that it didn't run, but you can't call it directly. Review lifecycle diagram here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: Guys, I want to call onResume() of the selected Activity from the ActivityGroup, which I think is possible.